# USE ROLLUP to compute grand total while displaying month names and sorting by month number

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is adapted from https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/using-the-rollup-cube-and-grouping-sets-operators.html

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, PurchaseDate) PurchaseMonth
     , CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, PurchaseDate) is null then 'Grand Total' 
                   ELSE coalesce (PurchaseType,'Monthly Total') end AS PurchaseType
     , Sum(PurchaseAmt) as SummorizedPurchaseAmt
FROM tPurchaseItem
GROUP BY   ROLLUP(DATENAME(month, PurchaseDate), PurchaseType);
```

This works but doesn't sort in chronological order.

The result is this:

[image]

I want the order to be January, February, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATENAME` returns a `nvarchar`, so the ordering will be like that of an `nvarchar`. `'April' < 'January'`.

One method would be to change your `GROUP BY` to `DATEPART` and derive the month's name from the number:

```
SELECT CHOOSE(DATEPART(MONTH, PurchaseDate),'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December') AS PurchaseMonth
     , CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, PurchaseDate) is null then 'Grand Total' 
                   ELSE coalesce (PurchaseType,'Monthly Total') end AS PurchaseType
     , Sum(PurchaseAmt) as SummorizedPurchaseAmt
FROM tPurchaseItem
GROUP BY   ROLLUP(DATEPART(MONTH, PurchaseDate), PurchaseType);
```